# JRI: how to get the console output in a Java String

Tags: rjava, jri

I declare the JRI engine as follows in my Java program:

```
REngine eng = REngine.engineForClass("org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine", 
    args, new REngineStdOutput(), false);
```

This works fine however I would like to get the console output in a Java String instead of the Java console.

I researched `REngineStdOutput` but couldn't find much. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement `org.rosuda.JRI.RMainLoopCallbacks` interface - in particular `rWriteConsole()` will be called with each output string.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is an example of how to show R output into Java. You basically have to implement [RMainLoopCallbacks](http://rforge.net/org/doc/org/rosuda/JRI/RMainLoopCallbacks.html).

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.RMainLoopCallbacks;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Runner {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Runner");

    static class LoggingConsole implements RMainLoopCallbacks {
        private Logger log;

        LoggingConsole(Logger log) {
            this.log = log;
        }

        public void rWriteConsole(Rengine re, String text, int oType) {
            log.info(String.format("rWriteConsole: %s", text));
        }

        public void rBusy(Rengine re, int which) {
            log.info(String.format("rBusy: %s", which));
        }

        public void rShowMessage(Rengine re, String message) {
            log.info(String.format("rShowMessage: %s",  message));
        }

        public String rReadConsole(Rengine re, String prompt, int addToHistory) {
            return null;
        }

        public String rChooseFile(Rengine re, int newFile) {
            return null;
        }

        public void rFlushConsole(Rengine re) {
        }

        public void rLoadHistory(Rengine re, String filename) {
        }

        public void rSaveHistory(Rengine re, String filename) {
        }
    }

    Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] {"--no-save"}, false, new LoggingConsole(log));
    ...
    // Use the engine somewhere to evaluate a R method and see the output
    engine.eval("library(caret)");
}
```